# Prove the order of an element divides the order of the group using cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know how to use cyclic groups and Lagrange's theorem to prove this, but I don't know how to use the notion of cosets to prove this.

Comment: The group is the disjoint union of the cosets of the subgroup generated by $a$.

Comment: What is $a$, an element of a group $G$? If $a$ generates a cyclic subgroup, how do you know which cosets there are in this subgroup?

Comment: $a$ is a generic element of $G$. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $a$. Then you look at the cosets $x\cdot H$ for $x\in G$. Two such cosets are either identical or disjoint.

Comment: $xH$ is only one coset though, what do you mean by by the plural 'cosets?'

Comment: One coset for every $x\in G$. Unless $G = H$, there are several cosets altogether.

Comment: I don't see any relationship between cosets and $|a|$ of an arbitrary $a \in G$ dividing $|G|$. What am I missing?

Comment: If $H$ is the subgroup generated by $a$, what is the order (i.e. number of elements) of $H$?

Comment: $|<a>| = |a|$, right? Other than that, I'm not sure if there's any other interesting properties with regards to the order. Like $|a|$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $a^k = e$ ($e$ is the identity element of $G$).

Comment: @user127001 There are two things you need to know: first, any cost $xH$ has the same order (why?), and second, any two cosets $xH$ and $yH$ are either identical or disjoint (why?)

Comment: For the first thing, $H$ has $|a|$ distinct elements so if you just multiply each element by some $x \in G$, you should get $|a|$ distinct elements because if two elements in the coset $xa_1$ and $xa_2$ are equal, then it means that $a_1 = a_2$ which is impossible because the two elements $a_1$ and $a_2$ are distinct in $H$. (Unsure if this is a valid "proof.") The second thing I am unsure about at the moment.

Comment: That proof is valid - but I think you're just reproving Lagrange's theorem now. It may help to know what your statement of Lagrange's theorem is exactly, because there are different versions, some of which will be more immediately helpful than others.

Answer (score 1):

To try to clean up some of the comments, I'll make an attempt at an answer. I'm not sure if this qualifies as "using cosets".

The actual proof is going to depend on the statement of Lagrange's theorem you have; my preferred version (for finite groups) is the following:

> If $G$ is a finite group, $H$ is a subgroup, and $|G:H|$ is the number
>   of (left, for sake of argument) cosets of $H$, then
>
> $$|G|=|H||G:H|$$

Thus, given $a\in G$, to prove that $|a|$ divides $|G|$ it is enough to find a subgroup $H$ such that $|H|=|a|$. But as you mention in the comments, $\langle a\rangle$ is such a subgroup, so you have the result.

If your version of Lagrange's theorem says something else, you may need to do more work; for example, it might simply state that $|G:H|$ divides $|G|$. In this case you will need to look at a proof, and see that (as is very likely!) it actually proves the identity I gave above. (Perhaps this is what you mean by using cosets; you can show that the number of cosets of $\langle a\rangle$ in $G$ divides $|G|$, and the result of this division is $|\langle a\rangle|=|a|$, so $|a|$ divides $|G|$ too.)